# ArrayFormula for consequential sum-up?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Here's a sample test spreadsheet - [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXZzwRnYpso_Q4PHd6M818oE347yRBAh9AqTLhqX8TM/edit?usp=sharing)

What do I have to do in the ONE cell in column D such that I won't have to copy and paste the same formula in column C throughout the entire column all the time as my data grows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allen, you can also try this:

1. Delete *everything* from Column D (including the header).
2. Place the following array formula into D1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Array Formula";SUMIF(ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B),B2:B)+B$1})`

Comment: Thanks! This work great! Except it leaves hundreds of extra rows at the bottom of the column.

Also, I wonder if there is a more generic way of using arrayformula if the intended operation is not a simple addition, but something more complex that still takes reference to the adjacent cell above or upwards diagonal?

Comment: You can remove superfluous row data with this addition to the formula: =ArrayFormula({"Array Formula";IF(B2:B="","",SUMIF(ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B),B2:B)+B$1)})

Comment: As for complex array formulas, I make a living from writing them. But there's not much I can tell you based on generalities. If you want to ask a specific question (or better yet, set up the scenario on your test sheet), I'll see what more I can offer based on that.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought that would work!

I have another scenario that I'd like you to solve. It is in the 2nd sheet of the same test link. :)

Comment: Allen, it's protocol on forums such as this to post one question per post. Otherwise, future searchers can't find answers.Please start a new post with the new question. You can include the same link.

Comment: Ok Erik, here goes! https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124481/arrayformula-for-conditional-consequential-sum-up

But before we move on to the next one, could you do some explanation of how your formula works? I don't get the "<=" operator in particular, its not "smaller or equal to", is it?

Comment: Yes. In English, the SUMIF reads, "In looking at all row numbers, for any row numbers less than or equal to the current row number at any given time, sum the values in column B for those rows only" (or, shortened, sum only rows up to "this point").

Answer (score 0):

- **if you want to clone column C to column D with `ARRAYFOORMULA` then use this:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(C1:C)
```

- **if you want `B1+B2` array:**

```
={{"ARRAYFORMULA FOR B1+B2"};
  {MMULT(B1:B30, TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(B2:B30)^0)))}}
```

- **if you want `B2+C2` array:**

```
={{"ARRAYFORMULA FOR B2+C2"};
  {MMULT(B2:C30, TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(B2:C30)^0)))}}
```

[image: 4]

Comment: Hmmm, this does not give the same results as the normal formula column, and I have no idea how those functions are working together with MMULT?

Comment: @AllenSierra what is your question?

Comment: Uh, well, I'm looking for an arrayformula based formula that gives the same results as the column C in my spreadsheet. :)