# ArrayFormula for conditional consequential sum-up?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a table which looks like this:

[image: 1]

And formula in cell B3: `=IF(A3>5, B2, B2+1)` and on every next row a corresponding variation of this formula.

I would like to know how to create ArrayFormula variant of this formula:

```
=IF(A3>5, B2, B2+1)
```

[spreadsheet sample here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXZzwRnYpso_Q4PHd6M818oE347yRBAh9AqTLhqX8TM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Allen, in the meantime, your sample sheet is "View Only." Please change the permissions to "Anyone with the link can Edit."

Comment: @MARK, if I'm understanding the OP correctly, he wants the Column B results generated by an array formula using only the data in Column A (i.e., he wants to replace the Column B results with an array), not use A and B to create a C or D. I could be wrong. But I do have an array to replace Column B, generating those results purely from the Column A data, when and if the OP edits the permissions of his sheet to allow editing, and when and if the hold is lifted on this post.

Comment: Permission updated. @~MMA, the solution works great, thank you. 
@Erik, I appreciate you  for coming over to help after the previous question. I'm good with MMA's answer, thanks anyway!

If either of you would explain how the IF-LEN works, that'd be perfect.

Comment: @AllenSierra `LEN` counts how many characters are in cell. `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), true, false))` checks every row in given range if its empty/not-empty. in other words this works like some check-in restriction. kinda same as `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", true, false))`

Comment: Allen, are you sure that @MARK's solution works without your existing Column B data in place (i.e., with only the raw data Column A)? I don't see how it could, since it references Column B ... which is what you're trying to replace. Try deleting your Column B manual results and see what happens.

Comment: As a fail safe, I've gone ahead and uploaded a formula into your sample sheet, Sheet2!B1: =ArrayFormula({"Result";IF(A2:A="","",COUNTIFS(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),A2:A,"<=5"))})

Comment: @~MMA is there any benefit (such as computation cost) for using "=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), true, false))" over " =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", true, false))"? I got a feeling the latter might cost less.

@Erik thanks for pointing that out. Your formula seem to work better at first glance, but it doesn't +1 at the correct (when A>5) row. Also I don't understand how it works in the first place when there is no mention of ADD or SUM in it.

Comment: @Allen, my formula results in a match to the image you posted in the original post. I'll wait for a reply to this point before I explain the formula.

Comment: @Allen, in addition to my formula producing results that match the image in your original post, the formula in your original post says (in English), "If the value in A is greater than five, don't add anything to the previous value; otherwise, add one."

Comment: @AllenSierra speed-wise `A1:A<>""` is same as `LEN(A1:A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=ArrayFormula({"Result";IF(A2:A="","",COUNTIFS(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),A2:A,"<=5"))})`

Answer (score 0):

probably not the answer OP is looking for, but here are some examples how to construct **`ARRAYFORMULA`** from **`=IF(A3>5, B2, B2+1)`**

[image]